# How to render json into a twig in Symfony2

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig

The question is how to pass a json to twig to render a template. I've tried to pass a json with JsonResponse object but I did not find the way to render the template.

TarifasController.php

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use AppBundle\Entity\Tarifa;

/**
 *
 * @Route("/tarifas")
 */
class TarifasController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="tarifa_index")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $tarifas = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Tarifa')->findAll();

        return $this->render('admin/tarifas/index.html.twig', array('tarifas' => $tarifas));
        //return new JsonResponse(array('json_tarifas' => json_encode($tarifas)));

    }
}
```

index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'admin/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body_id 'admin_post_show' %}

{% block main %}

    <h1>{{ 'label.project_list'|trans }}</h1>

    <table id="tarifas_index" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ 'Id' }}</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ 'label.title'|trans }}</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ 'label.summary'|trans }}</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ 'label.content'|trans }}</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> {{ 'label.actions'|trans }}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for tarifa in tarifas %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ tarifa.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ tarifa.codigo }}</td>
                <td>{{ tarifa.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ tarifa.razon }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="item-actions">
                        <a href="{{ path('project_detail', { id: tarifa.id }) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                            {{ 'action.show'|trans }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#tarifas_index').DataTable({
                data: tarifas
            });
        } );
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

How can I pass a json from the controller to use it in the DataTable (in twig template) but mantaining the render in this controller. Please, can you help me?

Comment: Can you please boil down your code examples until they only show the necessary parts?

Comment: I don't undestand it... Do you need to return a JSON encode string as response from action or do you want to use a JSON object as data provider in your template?

Comment: Yes, I want to use a json as a data provider, but I do not know how to do this from the controller to render a template

Comment: why don't you just decode the json data before sending it to twig? then you can use it as array or object, like you have in your twig file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve but you can simply send json encoded and normal data to your twig, to use it how you want

```
return $this->render('admin/tarifas/index.html.twig', array(
    'tarifas' => $tarifas
    'json_tarifas' => json_encode($tarifas)
));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can render like this,

```
return $this->render('admin/tarifas/index.html.twig', array(
    'tarifas' => $tarifas
    'json_tarifas' => json_encode($tarifas)
));
```

and retrieve like this in twig,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#tarifas_index').DataTable({
            data: $.parseJSON('{{ json_tarifas | raw }}')
        });
    } );
</script>
```